# Reusing a model, pretrained on 19 classes, for just one of those classes

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation, pretraining

I have a pretrained net for semantic segmentation, which has been trained on the cityscapes dataset and its 19 classes (Person, car, traffic sign, …). One of those is "Person". I am only interested in this class.

Is it beneficial to retrain the model on the same dataset for just one class instead of 19?

If yes, what is a good strategy?
Keep the weights for the feature extractors and just retrain the last classifying layer(s)?
Or tune all the weights?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have trained a semantic segmentation model for multiple classes in your case 19 classes and you only want to predict for one class that is the Person class. In this case, you will essentially be getting 4D output in the form of (B, C, H, W) where B is the batch size, C is the number of classes, and H and W are height/width respectively. You should consider C to 2 in your case i.e values other than Person class should be replaced by 0 whereas person class should be replaced by 1 in this way you will be able to make predictions only for person class without even retaining the model.

Comment: That is good input, thank you. I probably should mention in the question, that I am hoping for a performance increase due to the reduction to one class. That's why zeroing out the others, is not exactly what I am looking for.